# Printing a 2d array using a 1d array

Tags: c++, c

I am working on an eight queens/ chess board problem in my class. For my code, i am using a one dimensional array i.e q[c](c is the column) to store the value of the row which consists of a queen. for example, q[1]=3 means that in column 2 (0 based array), there is a queen in row 4.

The original problem used a 2d array, so b[r][c] would either = 0, or 1, 1 being a queen, 0 being the rest. The program used an ok function to test each queen it was placing against all previously placed queens, and at the end, printed the result.

```
The print function was
for(int j=0; j<c;j++)
   cout<<endl;
   for(int i=0; i<c;i++)
      cout<< b[i][j];
```

which printed 92 solution boards that looked something like this

```
10000000
00001000
01000000
00010000
00000010
00100000
00000100
00000001
```

Now for my issue:
I can NOT for the life of me figure out how to get the aforementioned 1d array b[c] to print a board which looks the same as this. I am a beginner comp sci student but i still thought this would be much more trivial.

I am not looking for an answer, more of a hint to lead me in the right direction, or maybe the first line of code. Help is MUCH appreciated. thanks

Comment: Hint: the naive way would just be: generate that 2D array from your 1D array, then print it the same way. If you go through that exercise you might hit on some better ideas.

Comment: In your last for you could check if i is equal to b[j] and print either 0 or 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like....

```
for (int y = 0; y<8; y++) {
   int val = b[y];
   for (int x=0; x<8; x++) {
      x==val ? printf("1") : printf("0") ;
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

or

```
    for (int y = 0; y<8; y++) {
       char[9] line;
       strcpy(line,"00000000");
       line[b[y]] = '1';
       printf("%s\n",line);
    }
```

Comment: thank you. i don't know how i didn't see it before but it all makes sense now! much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I guess that if your array would tell you in which *column* of each *row* a queen is, you'd figure out the solution easily.  Unfortunately, you have to produce your output row-by-row since that is how text terminals like it.  It's not that hard either:

- For each row:

  - For each column:

    - If there is a queen at (row, column): print 1, else print 0

You already have the code for this.  Except for the “if there is a queen…” part.  So let's break the problem up and make it a function:

```
bool is_there_a_queen(const int[8] board, int row, int col);
```

Will you be able to implement `is_there_a_queen`?

Comment: yes, i didn't include that part in the question sorry but i had a function that did all the checks (row, down diag, up diag) and used backtracking and goto's(thats the first way our professor showed us). this was very helpful tho, thank you

Comment: I remember that back then when we did the Eight Queens Problem in class, we made do without `goto`s…  Glad I could help, tough.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

/*
10000000
00001000
01000000
00010000
00000010
00100000
00000100
00000001
*/

int main()
{
   int q[] = {0, 4, 1, 3, 6, 2, 5, 7};
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i )
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j )
      {
         if ( q[i] == j )
         {
            std::cout << 1;
         }
         else
         {
            std::cout << 0;
         }
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks all for your help, i have utilized all your responses and figured it out, thanks again